# Spiral through arbitrary points on the imaginary axis

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, classical-mechanics

There are several points on the imaginary axis.

[image]

*Are there formulas that allow build a spiral that will pass through these points?*

Comment: The points $(0,1), (0,.5)$ don't look arbitrary. Are the points you marked in the drawing supposed to be $(0,1), (0,1/2), (0,1/3), (0,1/4), \ldots$? Or are they really arbitrary (in which case I wouldn't label them with $1$ and $.5$)?

Comment: @jjagmath numbers are absolutely arbitrary, they are equal to ${0.203455, 0.35332, 0.549904, 0.908859}$

Comment: So you want a formula for exactly those four points? Or do you expect a formula that can be applied to other four (or more) points?

Comment: @jjagmath I want to know if such formulas even exist for an arbitrary number of points and their values? I suppose that they can be very cumbersome, so I started with a small number of points (4 in this case).

Comment: Even for few (four) points there will be an infinity of spirals going through those points. Are you looking for a spiral with some specific properties?

Comment: @jjagmath To begin with, we can choose any spiral that goes through a set of given points and see how difficult it is to describe. After several iterations, it is desirable to come to the simplest mathematical description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use linear interpolation to construct a function $r(t)$ such that $r(0)=.2034$, $r(1)=.3533$, $r(2)=.5499$ and $r(3)=.9088$ and consider the spiral $s(t)=r(t)(-\sin(2\pi t),\cos(2\pi t))$

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/10ouv7axrf) is an example with the first two points.